# Error setting up mirroring on SQL databases after Sitecore upgrade

Tags: sql-database, contained-database

We have upgrade our website from `Sitecore 8.2 to 9.1.1`. As per sitecore upgrade guide I installed the XConnect separately and also restored Messaging, Processing Pools databases using `dacpac` files. I asked my database team to setup mirroring on all the databases but they are unable to setup mirroring on the following databases:

```
{clientname}_Processing.Pools
{clientname}_MarketingAutomation
{clientname}_Messaging
{clientname}_ReferenceData
{clientname}_ProcessingEngineTasks
{clientname}_ProcessingEngineStorage
{clientname}_Reporting
```

They are complaining that these databases are contained databases and can't be mirrored. The following is the exception they are getting:

```
An error occurred while starting mirroring.

===================================

Alter failed for Database '_ProcessingEngineTasks'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

------------------------------
For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=12.0.5556.0+((SQL14_SP2_QFE-CU).170817-1113)&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Alter+Database&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.AlterImpl()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.DBPropMirroring.StartMirroring(Object sender, EventArgs e)

===================================

Property DefaultLanguageName is not available for Database '[unitywater_ProcessingEngineTasks]'. This property may not exist for this object, or may not be retrievable due to insufficient access rights.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

------------------------------
For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=12.0.5556.0+((SQL14_SP2_QFE-CU).170817-1113)&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.PropertyCannotBeRetrievedExceptionText&EvtID=DefaultLanguageName&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.PropertyCollection.HandleNullValue(Int32 index)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.PropertyCollection.GetPropertyObject(Int32 index)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.GetPropertyOptional(String propName)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DefaultLanguage.VerifyBothLcidAndNameNotDirty(Boolean isLanguageValueNoneAllowed)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database.ContainmentRelatedValidation(ScriptingPreferences sp)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database.ScriptAlter(StringCollection alterQuery, ScriptingPreferences sp)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.AlterImplWorker()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.AlterImpl()
```

[image]

How do I get replication/mirroring setup for these databases?

Comment: You can try to change containment:
ALTER DATABASE {clientname}_Processing.Pools SET CONTAINMENT = NO